# djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: Error in django while filtering Data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, djongo

I am trying to filter my product list with price less than filter but getting error. I guess the error is I am unable to pass parameters correctly.
any help would be appreciated.

if you require anymore details, please ask.

Note: it does not works even if I pass the query on filter body static.

thanks in advance.

## my method:

```
def getfilter(request, format=None):
    kwargs = {
    '{0}__{1}'.format('price', 'lt'): Decimal('1000.00'),
    # '{0}__{1}'.format('name', 'endswith'): 'Z'
}

    products = Product.objects.all().filter(**kwargs)
    serializer = ProductSerializer1(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

## Error I Receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 806, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 934, in _select
    self._query = SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 113, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 153, in parse
    raise SQLDecodeError
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 55, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/Projects/python/loginBazaar/products/prodView.py", line 219, in getfilter
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 53, in execute
    params)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 743, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 826, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: SELECT "products_product"."id", "products_product"."name", "products_product"."vendorId", "products_product"."quantity", "products_product"."shopCode", "products_product"."discountPercent", "products_product"."discountPrice", "products_product"."price", "products_product"."dummyPrice", "products_product"."margin", "products_product"."description", "products_product"."is_verified", "products_product"."category", "products_product"."subCategory", "products_product"."images", "products_product"."sizeChart", "products_product"."attributes", "products_product"."buyCount", "products_product"."thumbnail", "products_product"."productCode", "products_product"."atts" FROM "products_product" WHERE "products_product"."price" < %(0)s ORDER BY "products_product"."productCode" ASC
Version: 1.2.32
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the conversion from Decimal to string failed:

```
'{0}__{1}'.format('price', 'lt'): Decimal('1000.00'),
```

and corresponding SQL:

```
< %(0)s
```

I guess one of this possible troubles:

- your model field `price` type is incorrect for this conversion
- your decimal value have two zero numbers after decimal point - try to
  remove the last one

Comment: i think the conversion failed too.. this is how the field is defined.:->       price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,decimal_places=2,max_digits=10)

Comment: And what happens if you remove last zero digit from decimal value in filter or explicitly cast a conversion to string `str(Decimal("1000.00"))`?

Comment: Nothing happens then.

Comment: I wonder whats the field type in the DB. You are using MongoDB, right?

Comment: yes mongodb. and in database it is showing as string

Comment: ok, and what about `price__lt="1000.0"` does this works? I have feeling that it's a wrong constraint on schema. If the DB field is string, then why your model saying it's a decimal?

Comment: I think it will not work because comparison on string and numerical value doesnt make sense. You need to update your DB schema.